# How to apply jquery on click of anker link that cantains class

Tags: jquery, razor

I have a dynamic anchor(`<a>` tag) link that create a class name

`<a class="modalCloseImg simplemodal-close" title="Close"></a>`

```
 $(".a.modalCloseImg").click(function () {
        alert("hi");
        var appName = document.getElementById("txtAppName").value;
        if (appName == "") {
            $.ajax({
                success: function () {
                    var tempUrl = "/Applications/Applications/";
                    window.location.href = tempUrl;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I want to know what it's right class name in which i apply click event.

Comment: have you loaded `jQuery`..??

Comment: `$(".a.modalCloseImg")` should be `$("a.modalCloseImg")` (remove the extra dot at beginning. Moreover, it would be better if you use an 'id' because there can be several elements with the same class.

Comment: Also, I think you mean `$("a.modalCloseImg")`, without the leading `.` before `a.modalCloseImg`

Comment: it's create class name at runtime like that <class=modalCloseImg simplemodal-close>

Comment: @AJayGarg use event delegation as explained by palash below.

Comment: I have already added jquery plugin

Answer (score 4):

Since the anchor is added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('click', 'a.modalCloseImg', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('testlink'); 
    // your code here...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".modalCloseImg").click(function () {
        alert("hi");
        var appName = document.getElementById("txtAppName").value;
        if (appName == "") {
            $.ajax({
                success: function () {
                    var tempUrl = "/Applications/Applications/";
                    window.location.href = tempUrl;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: can craete jsfiddle.net